# How to solve issue of maximum iteration getting exceeded in python gekko in this case (explained in the body)?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, gekko

I am trying to track multiple set-points in the case of interacting quadruple tank system process. Here, the upper limits of tanks are 25 and lower limits are 0. I want to track the set-point values of 5,12,7 and 5. Although, I am able to track the initial 3 set-points (i.e. 5,12 and 7), I am not able to track the last set-point due to solver exceeding max. iterations. I have attached the code below->

```
#MHE+MPC model

#to measure computational time of the code
start=time.time()

#Process Model
p = GEKKO(remote=False)
process=0
p.time = [0,0.5]
noise = 0.25

#Constants
g = 981
g1 = .9
g2 = .9
A1=32
A3=32
A2=32
A4=32
a1=0.057
a3=0.057
a2=0.057
a4=0.057
init_h=5

#Controlled process variables 
p.h1=p.SV(lb=0,ub=25)
p.h2=p.SV(lb=0,ub=25)
p.h3=p.SV(lb=0,ub=25)
p.h4=p.SV(lb=0,ub=25)

#Manipulated process variables
p.v1=p.MV(value=3.15,lb=0.1,ub=8)
p.v2=p.MV(value=3.15,lb=0.1,ub=8)

#Parameters of process
p.k1=p.Param(value=3.14,lb=0,ub=10)
p.k2=p.Param(value=3.14,lb=0,ub=10)

#Equations process
p.Equation(A1*p.h1.dt()==a3*((2*g*p.h3)**0.5)-(a1*((2*g*p.h1)**0.5))+(g1*p.k1*p.v1))
p.Equation(A2*p.h2.dt()==a4*((2*g*p.h4)**0.5)-(a2*((2*g*p.h2)**0.5))+(g2*p.k2*p.v2))
p.Equation(A3*p.h3.dt()==-a3*((2*g*p.h3)**0.5)+((1-g2)*p.k2*p.v2))
p.Equation(A4*p.h4.dt()==-a4*((2*g*p.h4)**0.5)+((1-g1)*p.k1*p.v1))

#options
p.options.IMODE = 4
#p.h1.TAU=-10^10
#p.h2.TAU=-10^10


#%% MHE Model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

#prediction horizon
m.time = np.linspace(0,40,41) #0-20 by 0.5 -- discretization must match simulation

#MHE control, manipulated variables and parameters
m.h1=m.CV(lb=0,ub=25)
m.h2=m.CV(lb=0,ub=25)
m.h3=m.SV(lb=0,ub=25)
m.h4=m.SV(lb=0,ub=25)

m.v1=m.MV(value=3.15,lb=0.10,ub=8)
m.v2=m.MV(value=3.15,lb=0.10,ub=8)

m.k1=m.FV(value=3.14,lb=0,ub=10)
m.k2=m.FV(value=3.14,lb=0,ub=10)

#m.h1.TAU=0
#m.h2.TAU=0

#Equations
m.Equation(A1*m.h1.dt()==a3*((2*g*m.h3)**0.5)-(a1*((2*g*m.h1)**0.5))+(g1*m.k1*m.v1))
m.Equation(A2*m.h2.dt()==a4*((2*g*m.h4)**0.5)-(a2*((2*g*m.h2)**0.5))+(g2*m.k2*m.v2))
m.Equation(A3*m.h3.dt()==-a3*((2*g*m.h3)**0.5)+((1-g2)*m.k2*m.v2))
m.Equation(A4*m.h4.dt()==-a4*((2*g*m.h4)**0.5)+((1-g1)*m.k1*m.v1))

#Options
m.options.IMODE = 5 #MHE
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2

# STATUS = 0, optimizer doesn't adjust value
# STATUS = 1, optimizer can adjust
m.v1.STATUS = 0
m.v2.STATUS = 0
m.k1.STATUS=1
m.k2.STATUS=1

m.h1.STATUS = 1
m.h2.STATUS = 1
#m.h3.STATUS = 0
#m.h4.STATUS = 0

# FSTATUS = 0, no measurement
# FSTATUS = 1, measurement used to update model
m.v1.FSTATUS = 1
m.v2.FSTATUS = 1
m.k1.FSTATUS=0
m.k2.FSTATUS=0

m.h1.FSTATUS = 1
m.h2.FSTATUS = 1
m.h3.FSTATUS = 1
m.h4.FSTATUS = 1

#m.options.MAX_ITER=1000
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.options.NODES=3

#%% MPC Model
c = GEKKO(remote=False)

c.time = np.linspace(0,10,11) #0-5 by 0.5 -- discretization must match simulation

c.v1=c.MV(value=3.15,lb=0.10,ub=8)
c.v2=c.MV(value=3.15,lb=0.10,ub=8)

c.k1=c.FV(value=3.14,lb=0,ub=10)
c.k2=c.FV(value=3.14,lb=0,ub=10)
#Variables
c.h1=c.CV(lb=0,ub=25)
c.h2=c.CV(lb=0,ub=25)
c.h3=c.SV(lb=0,ub=25)
c.h4=c.SV(lb=0,ub=25)
#Equations
c.Equation(A1*c.h1.dt()==a3*((2*g*c.h3)**0.5)-(a1*((2*g*c.h1)**0.5))+(g1*c.k1*c.v1))
c.Equation(A2*c.h2.dt()==a4*((2*g*c.h4)**0.5)-(a2*((2*g*c.h2)**0.5))+(g2*c.k2*c.v2))
c.Equation(A3*c.h3.dt()==-a3*((2*g*c.h3)**0.5)+((1-g2)*c.k2*c.v2))
c.Equation(A4*c.h4.dt()==-a4*((2*g*c.h4)**0.5)+((1-g1)*c.k1*c.v1))

#Options
c.options.IMODE = 6 #MPC
c.options.CV_TYPE = 2

# STATUS = 0, optimizer doesn't adjust value
# STATUS = 1, optimizer can adjust
c.v1.STATUS = 1
c.v2.STATUS = 1
c.k1.STATUS=0
c.k2.STATUS=0
c.h1.STATUS = 1
c.h2.STATUS = 1
#c.h3.STATUS = 0
#c.h4.STATUS = 0

# FSTATUS = 0, no measurement
# FSTATUS = 1, measurement used to update model
c.v1.FSTATUS = 0
c.v2.FSTATUS = 0
c.k1.FSTATUS=1
c.k2.FSTATUS=1
c.h1.FSTATUS = 1
c.h2.FSTATUS = 1
c.h3.FSTATUS = 1
c.h4.FSTATUS = 1


sp=5
c.h1.SP=sp
c.h2.SP=sp

p1 = GEKKO(remote=False)
p1.time = [0,0.5]


#Parameters

p1.h1=p1.CV(lb=0,ub=25)
p1.h2=p1.CV(lb=0,ub=25)
p1.h3=p1.CV(lb=0,ub=25)
p1.h4=p1.CV(lb=0,ub=25)

p1.v1=p1.MV(value=3.15,lb=0.1,ub=8)
p1.v2=p1.MV(value=3.15,lb=0.1,ub=8)

p1.k1=p1.Param(lb=0,ub=10,value=3.14)
p1.k2=p1.Param(lb=0,ub=10,value=3.14)

#Equations
p1.Equation(A1*p1.h1.dt()==a3*((2*g*p1.h3)**0.5)-a1*((2*g*p1.h1)**0.5)+g1*p1.k1*p1.v1)
p1.Equation(A2*p1.h2.dt()==a4*((2*g*p1.h4)**0.5)-a2*((2*g*p1.h2)**0.5)+g2*p1.k2*p1.v2)
p1.Equation(A3*p1.h3.dt()==-a3*((2*g*p1.h3)**0.5)+(1-g2)*p1.k2*p1.v2)
p1.Equation(A4*p1.h4.dt()==-a4*((2*g*p1.h4)**0.5)+(1-g1)*p1.k1*p1.v1)

#options
p1.options.IMODE = 4

#%% problem configuration
# number of cycles
cycles = 480
# noise level


#%% run process, estimator and control for cycles
h1_meas = np.empty(cycles)
h2_meas =np.empty(cycles)
h3_meas =np.empty(cycles)
h4_meas=np.empty(cycles)
h1_est = np.empty(cycles)
h2_est = np.empty(cycles)
h3_est = np.empty(cycles)
h4_est = np.empty(cycles)
h1_plant=np.empty(cycles)
h2_plant=np.empty(cycles)
h3_plant=np.empty(cycles)
h4_plant=np.empty(cycles)
h1_measured=np.empty(cycles)
h2_measured=np.empty(cycles)
h3_measured=np.empty(cycles)
h4_measured=np.empty(cycles)
v1_est = np.empty(cycles)
v2_est = np.empty(cycles)
k1_est = np.empty(cycles)
k2_est = np.empty(cycles)
u_cont_k1 = np.empty(cycles)
u_cont_k2 = np.empty(cycles)
sp_store = np.empty(cycles)
sum_est=np.empty(cycles)
sum_model=np.empty(cycles)

# Create plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.ion()
plt.show()

p.MAX_ITER=20
c.MAX_ITER=20
m.MAX_ITER=20
p1.MAX_ITER=20

for i in range(cycles):
    print(i)
    # set point changes
    if i==cycles/4:
        sp = 12
    elif i==2*cycles/4:
        sp = 7
    elif i==3*cycles/4:
        sp = 5
    
    
    sp_store[i] = sp
    c.h1.SP=sp
    c.h2.SP=sp
   
    c.k1.MEAS = m.k1.NEWVAL
    c.k2.MEAS = m.k2.NEWVAL

    if p.options.SOLVESTATUS == 1:
       # print("going:",i)
        c.h1.MEAS = p.h1.MODEL
        c.h2.MEAS = p.h2.MODEL
        c.h3.MEAS = p.h3.MODEL
        c.h4.MEAS = p.h4.MODEL
   
    print(i,'Plant Model:',p.h1.MODEL,p.h2.MODEL,p.h3.MODEL,p.h4.MODEL)
 
    c.solve(disp=False,debug=0)
        
    #print("NEWVAL:",i,c.u,c.u.NEWVAL)
    u_cont_k1[i] = c.v1.NEWVAL
    u_cont_k2[i] = c.v2.NEWVAL
    
    #print("Horizon:",i,c.h1[0:],c.h2[0:])
    #print("Move:",i,c.v1.NEWVAL,c.v2.NEWVAL)

    ## process simulator
    #load control move
    p.v1.MEAS = u_cont_k1[i]
    p.v2.MEAS = u_cont_k2[i]

    #simulate
 
    p.solve(disp=False,debug=0)
    
    #plant model
    p1.k1=3.14
    p1.k2=3.14
    p1.v1.MEAS = u_cont_k1[i]
    p1.v2.MEAS = u_cont_k2[i]
    p1.solve(disp=False,debug=0)
    
    h1_plant[i]=p1.h1.MODEL
    h2_plant[i]=p1.h2.MODEL
    h3_plant[i]=p1.h3.MODEL
    h4_plant[i]=p1.h4.MODEL
    
    h1_measured[i]=p1.h1.MODEL+(random()*2)*noise
    h2_measured[i]=p1.h2.MODEL+(random()*2)*noise
    h3_measured[i]=p1.h3.MODEL+(random()*2)*noise
    h4_measured[i]=p1.h4.MODEL+(random()*2)*noise
    
    
    #print("Model process output:",i,p.h1.MODEL,p.h2.MODEL,p.h3.MODEL,p.h4.MODEL)
    #load output with white noise
    h1_meas[i] = p.h1.MODEL+(random()-0.5)*noise
    h2_meas[i] = p.h2.MODEL+(random()-0.5)*noise
    h3_meas[i] = p.h3.MODEL+(random()-0.5)*noise
    h4_meas[i] = p.h4.MODEL+(random()-0.5)*noise
    
    #Only MPC
    

    ## estimator
    #load input and measured output
    m.v1.MEAS = u_cont_k1[i]
    m.v2.MEAS = u_cont_k2[i]
    #m.h1.MEAS = h1_meas[i]+(random()*2)*noise
    #m.h2.MEAS = h2_meas[i]+(random()*2)*noise
    #m.h3.MEAS = h3_meas[i]+(random()*2)*noise
    #m.h4.MEAS = h4_meas[i]+(random()*2)*noise
    m.h1.MEAS = h1_meas[i]
    m.h2.MEAS = h2_meas[i]
    m.h3.MEAS = h3_meas[i]
    m.h4.MEAS = h4_meas[i]
    #m.COLDSTART=2
    #optimize parameters
    
       
    m.solve(disp=False,debug=0)
    #store results
    if i>=process:
        h1_est[i] = m.h1.MODEL
        h2_est[i] = m.h2.MODEL
        h3_est[i] = m.h3.MODEL
        h4_est[i] = m.h4.MODEL
        v1_est[i] = m.v1.NEWVAL
        v2_est[i] = m.v2.NEWVAL
        k1_est[i]= m.k1.NEWVAL
        k2_est[i] = m.k2.NEWVAL
        
    print("Estimated h:",i,h1_est[i],h2_est[i],h3_est[i],h4_est[i])
    print("Estimated k:",i,k1_est[i],k2_est[i],p.k1[0],p.k2[0])
    print("Estimated v:",i,v1_est[i],v2_est[i])
    print("dh1/dt:",(a3*((2*g*h3_est[i])**0.5)-(a1*((2*g*h3_est[i])**0.5))+(g1*k1_est[i]*v1_est[i]))/A3)
    print("dh2/dt:",(a4*((2*g*h4_est[i])**0.5)-(a2*((2*g*h2_est[i])**0.5))+(g2*k2_est[i]*v2_est[i]))/A2)
    print("dh3/dt:",(-a3*((2*g*h3_est[i])**0.5)+((1-g2)*k2_est[i]*v2_est[i]))/A3)
    print("dh4/dt:",(-a4*((2*g*h4_est[i])**0.5)+((1-g1)*k1_est[i]*v1_est[i]))/A4)
    
    if i%1==0:
        plt.clf()
        plt.subplot(4,1,1)
        #plt.plot(h1_meas[0:i])
        #plt.plot(h2_meas[0:i])
        #plt.plot(h3_meas[0:i])
        #plt.plot(h4_meas[0:i])
        plt.plot(h1_est[0:i])
        plt.plot(h2_est[0:i])
        plt.plot(sp_store[0:i])
        
        
        plt.subplot(4,1,2)
        
        plt.plot(h3_est[0:i])
        plt.plot(h4_est[0:i])
        
        #plt.legend(('h1_pred','h2_pred','h3_pred','h4_pred'))


        plt.subplot(4,1,3)
        plt.plot(k1_est[0:i])
        plt.plot(k2_est[0:i])


        plt.subplot(4,1,4)
        plt.plot(v1_est[0:i])
        plt.plot(v2_est[0:i])
        
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.05)
end=time.time()
print("total time:",end-start)
```

I feel there is some issue with my MHE+MPC code. However, I am not able to realize the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Nice application. I needed a few imports to make the script work. These may be loaded automatically for you.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random
```

[image: successful solution]

The script solves successfully if a lower bound is included on all the level variables (`1e-6`). There is a problem when the level goes below zero or is at zero when using `m.sqrt()`. This small adjustment helps it solve successfully so it doesn't get into a region where it is undefined. Gekko solvers can't deal with imaginary numbers.

Although the solution is successful, it appears that the control performance oscillates. There may need to be some [tuning of the application](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerTuning).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I forgot to add imports in the code which I pasted on stack overflow. Although I had included the imports in jupyter.
I am still not able to attain certain set-point values (ex: if I give set-point as 5-15-5, I am able to reach 5 and 15 but not able to attain set-point of 5.) Although, the code works just fine with some set-point values such as 5-10-20. I am specifically not able to understand why it is able to track certain set-points but fails at others. I would request if you could clarify this doubt!

Comment: Could you check if the MV is saturating and can't adjust further? It may be a constraint that is preventing the solution. Also, check the objective function value. It should be non-zero when not at the set point.